# Meaning of Yiddish expression

Tags: yiddish

There is a Yidish expression "Vi Ah Grude Michel" - What does it mean and where did it originate?

Comment: Where did you hear/see it, and in what context?

Comment: It is said as a "He is a real straight fellow" however I am not sure where the Michel comes in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means what everyone is saying "He is a real straight fellow" But Mekel means a meek person it means more he does not have it in him to lie.

Comment: Its a very common term to regular yiddish speakers

Comment: From Googling a bit, the term seems to be גראדע מעכל.